# Sockets,BufferedWriter.flush() not sending the data

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader, serversocket, bufferedwriter

The following code works ,the server gets the `com` string and then the connection closes,if I uncomment the `bw.flush()` and its next line ,The server doesn't get the com string anymore and it just waits on the `br.readLine()` for a response(which will not get since the server didn't got the com string),if I move the `bw.close()` and put it in the `bw.flush()` position the `br.readLine()` will throw a Socket closed exception.

```
public static void setupClient(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
    Socket client = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName(), Server.DEFAULT_COMMAND_PORT);
    BufferedWriter  bw =new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
    BufferedReader  br =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
    String com=args[0]+(args.length==2?args[1]:"");
    bw.write(com);
//  bw.flush();
//  System.out.println("response:"+br.readLine());
    bw.close();
    client.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading lines but you aren't writing lines. `readLine()` returns when it reads a line terminator or end of stream. That's why it works when the peer closes instead of flushing. You need to use `BufferedWriter.newLine()` after your `write().`